# How do I create a ROS enabled Android app?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm a newbie on ROS and ROSJava and I'm trying write an app which communicates with ROS on a PC. The PC has ROS Hydro installed. I've followed the steps so now I have rosjava_core and android_core. And I was trying to import the tutorials from android_core in Android Studio to test the waters and start playing around but I get a message about unsupported version of Gradle (which is weird because it's using the one that came with AS). I have v1.8 of Gradle. When I am not getting that problem I get **"Could not find any version that matches org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap:gradle_plugins:[0.1,0.2).Required by:android_core:unspecified"**
I've followed the tutorials as closely as possible but I can't seem to find a solution.
Any help would be very appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104851/how-do-i-create-a-ros-enabled-android-app?/) by [MariosV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9191/mariosv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-11-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MariosV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9191/mariosv/) on 2014-02-09**:
After a lot of messing around and your help I managed to solve my problems.
a) I was sourcing the wrong setup.bash file so I got the "Could not find..." problem.
b) The Gradle problem seemingly solved itself.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the Gradle version, try to change the Gradle version number in the wrapper folder of android_core (android_core/gradle/wrapper/gradle....properties).
For the rojava_bootstrap... error check this post //answers.ros.org/question/100271/importing-android_core-failed/

---

Originally posted by [dtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/8716/dtc/) with karma: 41 on 2013-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DmitryDzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/6124/dmitrydzz/) on 2014-01-08**:
This answer help me. Thanks Dtc. What exactly I did:

1. I installed Gradle 1.9 (not 1.10!)
2. Cloned android_core
3. cd .../android_core/android_tutorial_camera
4. catkin_make
5. source devel/setup.bash
6. .../android-studio/bin/studio.sh
7. Then selected "Import project" and android_code directory